# Validator v10 get list of error on single field

Tags: validation, go

Is there a way to get the list of errors for each validation that fails?
Currently I'm just receiving one error, and comes from the first validation that fails.

I'm using golang and Validator v10

```
type User struct {
    ID          string   `param:"id" json:"id" validate:"required"`
    Name        string   `json:"name" validate:"required,max=100"`
    Permissions []string `json:"permissions" validate:"permission_list,distinct_list"`
}
```

So if the field Permissions fails on both I can get as result:

```
{
    "validationErrors": {
        "permissions": [
            "permissions must be a list of valid permissions",
            "permissions must be uniques",
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to inspect the error returned.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

type User struct {
    FirstName      string     `validate:"required"`
    LastName       string     `validate:"required"`
}

func main() {
    testUser := User{}

    v := validator.New()
    
    if err := v.Struct(testUser); err != nil {
        validationErrors := err.(validator.ValidationErrors)
        for _, validationError := range validationErrors {
            fmt.Println(validationError.Error())
        }
    }
}
```

Example:
https://play.golang.com/p/HFdHrPKiYwF

Check the code at https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/master/errors.go for methods available on `ValidationErrors` and `FieldError`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is not just only check one validate condition then return it, but need to check every validate that failed instead, you need to do a little enhancement on the package, like my case. I need to remove `return` statement from `validator.go` [source](https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/master/validator.go) on line 480